# How can I update email in Reactnative and firebase If I have both provider combined, that is phone and password linked together

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

this is my code

```
const handleSaveEmail = async () => {
    try {
      if (!currentUser) {
        console.log("User is not available");
        return;
      }
      console.log("Provider Data:", currentUser.providerData);
      const newEmail = updatedEmail.trim();
      console.log("Updated Email:", newEmail);


  if (newEmail === "") {
    console.log("Email cannot be empty");
    return;
  }

  // Find the "password" provider in the provider data
  const passwordProvider = currentUser.providerData.find(
    (provider) => provider.providerId === "password"
  );

  if (passwordProvider) {
    console.log("User is authenticated with email/password");

    try {
      // Update the email for the "password" provider
      await updateEmail(currentUser,newEmail);

      // Update the local state
      setUpdatedEmail(newEmail);
      setIsEditingEmail(false);

      console.log("Email update successful for password provider");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error updating email for password provider:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("User is not authenticated with email/password");
    console.log("You may need to handle this case as needed.");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error updating email:", error);
}
```

};

**In my console log I get
Provider Data: [{"displayName": null, "email": null, "phoneNumber": "+11234567890", "photoURL": null, "providerId": "phone", "uid": "+11234567890"}, {"displayName": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "phoneNumber": null, "photoURL": null, "providerId": "password", "uid": "xyz@gmail.com"}]**

I am getting user data from current user

> The error I get is Error updating email for password provider:
> [TypeError: undefined is not a function]